# Invariant products of holomorphic differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$ with automorphism group $G$. Is there a nice way to describe which products of holomorphic differentials on $C$ are invariant under the action of $G$?

If we're just looking for $G$-invariant holomorphic differentials in general, then these correspond to holomorphic differentials on the quotient $C/G$ (which you can describe in terms of the degree of the projection map and the ramification divisor using the Riemann-Hurwitz formula). However, invariant products aren't necessarily products of invariant differentials.

Finally, is there a nice way to estimate the terms involved in the Riemann-Hurwitz formula (e.g. in terms of the signature of the group action)?

Comment: Are differentials on C/G a "useful" description? Unless I'm missing something, C/G probably isn't a space that is easy to describe or understand.

Comment: Yes, $C/G$ is definitely an interesting/useful description. I think my point was that I wanted to understand when the /products/ are invariant, which doesn't necessarily mean that the individual differentials we take products of correspond to ones on $C/G$.